# How do I create an observable on core data and bind it to tableView

Tags: uitableview, observable, bind, rx-swift

I fetch `core data` like this:

```
var persistingData: [MyDataObject] = coreData.fetchAll(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<MyDataObject>(entityName: "MyDataObject"))
```

Now how do I go about using this data for an `Observable` that can `bind` the data to an `rx` `tableView`?

Do I create an `observable` like this:

```
func fetchAllData() -> Observable<[MyDataObject]> {
    var persistingData: [MyDataObject] = coreData.fetchAll(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<MyDataObject>(entityName: "MyDataObject"))

    return Observable.create({ observable in
        observable.onNext(persistingData)
        observable.onCompleted()
        return Disposables.create()
    })
}
```

But then how I use `bind()` on the `observable` if I pass the data to `onNext`? `bind` is used directly on the `method` like so:

```
fetchAllData().bind()
```

How do I actually get the `data` into the `observable` so that it can be used in `bind()`?

***EDIT***

I tried like this as well. Is this a valid way of doing it?

```
func fetchAllData() -> PublishRelay<[MyDataObject]> {
    var persistingData: [MyDataObject] = coreData.fetchAll(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<MyDataObject>(entityName: "MyDataObject"))

    let relay = PublishRelay<[LocalDoorCoreDataObject]>()
    relay.accept(persistingDoors)
    return relay
}
```

Then you can `bind` to it like this:

```
viewModel.fetchAllData().bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: Cell.identifier, cellType: Cell.self)) { row, data, cell in

    cell.viewModel = data

}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Does this seem reasonable, or is there some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rx is particularly useful when handling streams of data, but you are trying to use it as a simple wrapper around a single Core Data fetch request. I'd build a `BehaviorRelay` to keep a copy of the data coming from Core Data, and an Observable that runs your fetch request and reports values to the `BehaviorRelay` that you can subscribe to any time you need to refresh.

Having in your view model:

```swift
let data = BehaviorRelay<[MyDataObject]>(value: [])
```

I would bind it to your table view:

```swift
viewModel.data.bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: Cell.identifier, cellType: Cell.self)) { row, data, cell in
    cell.viewModel = data

}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

And then, back in your view model:

```swift
var loadData: Observable<[MyDataObject]> {
   return Observable.deferred { [unowned self] in
      return Observable.just(self.coreData.fetchAll(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<MyDataObject>(entityName: "MyDataObject")))
   }.do(onNext: { [unowned self] data in
      self.data.accept(data)
   }
}
```

Anytime you need to refresh data, you just call:

```swift
viewModel.loadData.subscribe().disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

*You can use the value emitted by `loadData` to make immediate changes to your UI, such as displaying an empty screen or stopping the loading indicator. If you do, make sure to add `observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)` before subscribing.*

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with your fetch.

```swift
func fetchAllData() -> Observable<[MyDataObject]> {
    Observable.just(coreData.fetchAll(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<MyDataObject>(entityName: "MyDataObject")))
}
```

(The above does the same thing your fetchAllData did, but is more concise.)

Now think of all the reasons you might want to fetch data... Let's say you have a refresh button and the only time you want to fetch all the data is when the user taps that button. Then in your `viewDidLoad` (or in a function that is called from it,) you would have:

```swift
let allData = refreshButton.rx.tap 
    .flatMap { 
        fetchAllData()
    }
```

and let's say we want to display data on a table view. What are all the reasons we would want to reload the data on the view? Let's say that the only reason we would want to reload the data is when `allData` emits a value. Then also in the `viewDidLoad` (or a function called from it) you would have:

```swift
allData
    .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: Cell.identifier, cellType: Cell.self)) { row, data, cell in
        cell.viewModel = data
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

There we go, that simple.

Now of course things will get more complex when you envision other times when you might want to fetch all data, but the above is the basics.